# Analytically minimize sum of products

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

I am having the following function of 2 variables which I would like to minimize.

$$ f(x,y)={\left(n_{1}\right)\left(1- x\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}\right)^{T}} + {\left(n_{2}\right)\left(1- y\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}\right)^{T}}$$

> > Note that $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0,1]$. In fact, $x$ and $y$ are probability values.
>
> T is a positive integer. (T actually denotes number of tests in my actual problem.) $n_1$ and $n_2$ are also positive integers but much larger than T. ( $n_1$ and $n_2$ represents number of members in  2 classes in my actual problem setup).
>
> $k_1$ and $k_2$ represents number of defective members in the two classes containing $n_1$ and $n_2$ members each. Thus, $T$ can be viewed as the number of tests made to identify the defective members.

The only way I can think of is take the partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$ and equate them to zero and solve simultaneously.

I tried this, but I don't see any ways of solving the resulting 2 equations as they are not analytically simple atleast for me.

I also notice that, there is some sort of symmetry in $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$. My hunch is that this could be made use of to find a minimum.

> > Can someone suggest a possible way of solving it?

One more question:

> > **Is there any computer software package or online tools that I can use to minimize this function while keeping the generic letter constants as such?**

Comment: Do not dream too much. This is a real monster. Cheers :-)

Comment: Jyotish, Let  $g(x,y)=1-x(1-x)^{k_1}(1-y)^{k_2}$ and $h(x,y)=1-y(1-x)^{k_1}(1-y)^{k_2}$. If g(x, y) and h(x, y) are minimum then f(x, y) is minimum. I took derivative and equate it to zero. I found that the minimum of g(x,y) and h(x, y) is zero. So minimum of f(x, y) is $n_1+n_2$.

Comment: @sirous , so did you minimize g(x,y) and h(x,y) separately? I think the 2 functions are not minimized for the same (x,y) values. Thus, the sum is not minimized at this point. do you agree?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ,  I tried to empirically find the point of minimum. I found that the solution is  very close to  $x =y= \frac{1}{k1+k2+1}$. Note that n1, n2, k1, k2 and T are positive integers and n1>> k1 and n2>>k2.  Do you think atleast  it is possible to prove this claim?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the parameters?  The behaviour of $f$ depends very strongly on the *signs* of the parameters.  Are $x$, $y$, and the parameters integers? rational? real? complex?  Your proposal of taking derivatives suggests $x$ and $y$ are real or complex, but doesn't provide insight into the domain of the parameters.

Comment: @EricTowers , I have added the required information as an edit .

Answer (score 3):

$f(x,y)=\left(n_{1}\right)\left(1-x\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}\right)^{T}+\left(n_{2}\right)\left(1-y\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}\right)^{T}$

define $\alpha=\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}$

$f(x,y)=\left(n_{1}\right)\left(1-x\alpha(x,y)\right)^{T}+\left(n_{2}\right)\left(1-y\alpha(x,y)\right)^{T}$

minimize with a Lagrange multiplier:

$\left(n_{1}\right)\left(1-x\alpha\right)^{T}+\left(n_{2}\right)\left(1-y\alpha\right)^{T}+\lambda(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}-\alpha)$

$\partial_{x}:-\left(T\alpha n_{1}\right)\left(1-x\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\lambda k_{1}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}-1}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}})=0$

$\partial_{y}:-\left(T\alpha n_{2}\right)\left(1-y\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\lambda k_{2}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}-1})=0$

$\partial_{\alpha}:-\left(xTn_{1}\right)\left(1-x\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\left(yTn_{2}\right)\left(1-y\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\lambda=0$

multiplying the first two equations by $\frac{x}{\alpha};\frac{y}{\alpha}$
  respectively:

$-\left(Txn_{1}\right)\left(1-x\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\lambda xk_{1}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}-1}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}})/\alpha=0$

$-\left(Tyn_{2}\right)\left(1-y\alpha\right)^{T-1}-\lambda yk_{2}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}-1})/\alpha=0$

subtracting from the $\partial_{\alpha}$
 term:

$-xk_{1}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}-1}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}})/\alpha-yk_{2}(\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}-1})/\alpha+1=0$

using the constraint $\alpha=\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}$
  ( we are allowed to use it now that we have finished differentiating):

$-xk_{1}(\frac{\alpha}{1-x})/\alpha-yk_{2}(\frac{\alpha}{1-y})/\alpha+1=0$

yielding:

$k_{1}(\frac{x}{1-x})+k_{2}(\frac{y}{1-y})=1$

We can now eliminate $y$
  and solve for a one dimensional minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going through it. I am aware of lagrange multipliers when there are equality constraints. Here you are defining $\alpha$ to explicitly bring in an equality constraint and then using Lagrange multipliers with that constraint. Is this a well-known trick?

Comment: It just seemed to me a clean way to identify the common $\left(1-x\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-y\right)^{k_{2}}$ term. I was surprised myself when I saw that I could eliminate one term regardless of the value of the multiplier. Maybe there is a direct way to do this, but I haven't looked.